# Android FingerPaint Sample Draws Four Lines

Tags: android, graphics, drawing

I am trying to follow the code for the FingerPaint example provided in Android's APIDemos sample project.  In my case (unless this is supposed to happen), four mirrored lines are being drawn, instead of **one line under the user's finger**, which is what I want.  I have not made any changes to the code:

```
package com.example.android.apis.graphics;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.*;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class FingerPaint extends GraphicsActivity
        implements ColorPickerDialog.OnColorChangedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new MyView(this));

        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(12);

        mEmboss = new EmbossMaskFilter(new float[] { 1, 1, 1 },
                                       0.4f, 6, 3.5f);

        mBlur = new BlurMaskFilter(8, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL);
    }

    private Paint       mPaint;
    private MaskFilter  mEmboss;
    private MaskFilter  mBlur;

    public void colorChanged(int color) {
        mPaint.setColor(color);
    }

    public class MyView extends View {

        private static final float MINP = 0.25f;
        private static final float MAXP = 0.75f;

        private Bitmap  mBitmap;
        private Canvas  mCanvas;
        private Path    mPath;
        private Paint   mBitmapPaint;

        public MyView(Context c) {
            super(c);

            mPath = new Path();
            mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
            super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
            mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.drawColor(0xFFAAAAAA);

            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);

            canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        }

        private float mX, mY;
        private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

        private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
            mPath.reset();
            mPath.moveTo(x, y);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
        private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
            float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
            float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
            if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
                mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
                mX = x;
                mY = y;
            }
        }
        private void touch_up() {
            mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
            // commit the path to our offscreen
            mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
            // kill this so we don't double draw
            mPath.reset();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    touch_start(x, y);
                    invalidate();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    touch_move(x, y);
                    invalidate();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    touch_up();
                    invalidate();
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    private static final int COLOR_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST;
    private static final int EMBOSS_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST + 1;
    private static final int BLUR_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST + 2;
    private static final int ERASE_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST + 3;
    private static final int SRCATOP_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST + 4;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

        menu.add(0, COLOR_MENU_ID, 0, "Color").setShortcut('3', 'c');
        menu.add(0, EMBOSS_MENU_ID, 0, "Emboss").setShortcut('4', 's');
        menu.add(0, BLUR_MENU_ID, 0, "Blur").setShortcut('5', 'z');
        menu.add(0, ERASE_MENU_ID, 0, "Erase").setShortcut('5', 'z');
        menu.add(0, SRCATOP_MENU_ID, 0, "SrcATop").setShortcut('5', 'z');

        /****   Is this the mechanism to extend with filter effects?
        Intent intent = new Intent(null, getIntent().getData());
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
        menu.addIntentOptions(
                              Menu.ALTERNATIVE, 0,
                              new ComponentName(this, NotesList.class),
                              null, intent, 0, null);
        *****/
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        mPaint.setXfermode(null);
        mPaint.setAlpha(0xFF);

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case COLOR_MENU_ID:
                new ColorPickerDialog(this, this, mPaint.getColor()).show();
                return true;
            case EMBOSS_MENU_ID:
                if (mPaint.getMaskFilter() != mEmboss) {
                    mPaint.setMaskFilter(mEmboss);
                } else {
                    mPaint.setMaskFilter(null);
                }
                return true;
            case BLUR_MENU_ID:
                if (mPaint.getMaskFilter() != mBlur) {
                    mPaint.setMaskFilter(mBlur);
                } else {
                    mPaint.setMaskFilter(null);
                }
                return true;
            case ERASE_MENU_ID:
                mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(
                                                        PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
                return true;
            case SRCATOP_MENU_ID:
                mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(
                                                    PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP));
                mPaint.setAlpha(0x80);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

The picture ends up looking like (I was scribbling in the middle of the screen):

[image]

This is my first jump into drawing code like this since school, so my understanding of it is a bit shaky at the moment.  I want to draw a line that follows the user's finger.

Comment: @nicholas.hauschild I want to a single line that follows the user's finger

Answer (score 0):

Hi there is an other file in library with the name of GraphicActivity. code is as following.

```
enter code herepublic class GraphicsActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  }

   @Override
  public void setContentView(View view){
    if (false){ // set to true to test Picture
        ViewGroup vg = new PictureLayout(this);
        vg.addView(view);      
        view = vg;
    }        
    super.setContentView(view);
  }
 }
```

this will provide you single line against your finger touch.